# Changing a parameter while branching in SCIP

Tags: scip, operations-research, branch-and-bound, pyscipopt

I use pyscipopt. I know how to add constraints while branching using handlers (kind of), but now I also want to change some parameters. I imagine that is similar, but couldn’t found an example.

What I want is as follows: -Every time a feasible node is found (or every 10 nodes for example) update a parameter.

How do I do this? Are there examples or documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement an event handler. Look in `test_eventy.py` for an example. The eventtype should be SCIP_EVENTTYPE_NODEBRANCHED. Then you can change parameters in the exec callback.